# Stripe Connection Error

Tags: node.js, angular, stripe-payments

I have the follow backend Node.js code to connect to my Stripe account to make a Charge. But I'm getting this error. I'm using Firebase Functions, and this functionality used to work before, so I doubt this is anything to do with Firebase access restrictions. Any ideas and help on this will be greatly appreciated!

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

exports.stripePay = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    var app = express();
    var router = express.Router();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cors());

    var stripetoken = request.body.cardToken;
    var amountpayable = request.body.amount;

    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amountpayable,
      currency: 'usd',
      source: stripetoken,
      description: 'Sample transaction'
    }, function (err, charge) {
      console.log("ST4");
      if (err) {
        response.send("Failed!");
      }
      else {
        response.send({ success: true });
      }
    })
  }

{ Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe
    at Error._Error (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:12:17)
    at Error.Constructor (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:98:13)
    at Error.Constructor (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:98:13)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:192:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1020:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)   type: 'StripeConnectionError', stack: 'Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe\n    at Error._Error (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:12:17)\n    at Error.Constructor (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:98:13)\n    at Error.Constructor (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:98:13)\n    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:192:9)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)\n    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)\n    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1020:8)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)',   rawType: undefined,   code: undefined,   param: undefined,   message: 'An error occurred with our connection to Stripe',   detail:     { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.stripe.com api.stripe.com:443
       at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'api.stripe.com',
     host: 'api.stripe.com',
     port: '443' },   raw:     { message: 'An error occurred with our connection to Stripe',
     detail: 
      { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.stripe.com api.stripe.com:443
          at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
          at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
        code: 'ENOTFOUND',
        errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
        hostname: 'api.stripe.com',
        host: 'api.stripe.com',
        port: '443' } },   requestId: undefined,   statusCode: undefined } Reply
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

this is a good one! Firebase blocks external API connections for Free accounts, just get any paid account and this will work!

Comment: are you sure about this? I have two projects, both under same account and both unpaid projects, however stripe connect works for one of them and not the other

Comment: If you authorise that it works even in free version. If you want to deal with un-authorised users, only paid version.

Comment: @Dimitri how do you authorize? do you mean allow stripe as an external api in the firebase account?

Comment: @mitrenegade No, the users (clients) which will need to access this must be authorized (logged in). This is easily done as Firebase offers make out of the box solutions like Facebook login or a simple email+password registration/login. So you could just manually create a user (email+pass) in Auth section of Firebase, and via this user do your business. Then it will work. Alternatively just get the paid on the go account which will cost you pennies per month at most with little traffic.

Comment: your answer save me

Comment: Wow that was a good one, very helpful.  Logging in as an authorized user did not work for me I had to upgrade.  Having to pay for Dev environment now is not ideal though.

Answer (score 1):

Dimitris answer is correct, in more layman's terms simply get on the blaze plan and you can make calls to stripe api from Firebase Functions.