# Firebase - An error occurred with our connection to Stripe

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm running Firebase Cloud Functions to connect to Stripe for things such as charges, cancellations, etc.

I also have a cron task that is a Cloud Function that is called from App Engine daily. This downgrades user plans based on certain logic.

When running the cron on Firebase it runs perfectly every time. Although when running it locally I get the following error every time:

```
Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe
```

I found two similar answers, although both are referring to upgrading from a free plan to a paid plan. My Firebase plan is definitely Blaze (pay as you go).

- [Stripe Connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024530)
- [Error connecting to Stripe from Firebase Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447966)

Why am I getting this error when my Firebase project is a paid plan? Is it different because I'm running the functions locally?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing your code...

Comment: @grooveplex this is not a code issue - it is a platform/service (Firebase) issue.

Comment: Any update? I have the same problem when I create a new stripe customer but creating a charge works just fine...

Comment: @Fizzix have you found a solution? thanks

Comment: Seems to be a weird issue on local only. Occurs a couple of times a day and just requires me to restart my local server.